# windowsform, checkbox, button clicks

Tags: c#, winforms

My question is regarding c# windows form.

I have three checkboxes in a form:

> checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3

and a button.

The button programming is this:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
        }
        else
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
        }
        else
        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
        }
        else
            if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
        {
        }
        else
        if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)
        {
        }
        else
        if (checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)
          {
          }
        else
      if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)
        {
        }
        else
        {
    MessageBox.Show("Please Select an Checkbox to Perform");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
    }
```

My problem is that when if I check all three checkboxes it goes through the whole if statements within the button, 
it processes all functions within the button, 
I want that when i check all checkboxes its should perfon only this statement, and other as checked.

```
//If(checkbox1.checked && Checkbox2.checked && checkbox3.Checked) {}
```

and so on

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide a meaningful, descriptive problem or question instead of a salutation and regurgitation of the tag information.

Comment: Then move your if statements around...

Comment: That's the most horrible formatting/indentation of if-statements I've ever seen.

Comment: thanks everyone.. I am new to C# .. just started a few days ago.. and i got a class project to perform..

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate options

1. Change the order of the `if` statements so they are in the order you prefer them to be checked.
2. or better, test the state of all checkboxes in each `if` statement; that is, don't just test if some are checked and assume the rest are unchecked -- test the unchecked checkboxes as well.  Be explicit!

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on your main logic of your code. Here's a simple solution for your problem. First check all of them, then only groups of them, then individually.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)//checking all of them first
        {

        }
        else if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)//checking only pairs
        {

        }
        else if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)//checking only pairs
        {

        }
        else if (checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)//checking only pairs
        {

        }
        else//check them here individually
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {

            }
            else if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {

            }
            else if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {

            }
            else//none of them are checked
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you Attila.. i already figure it out.. as i am new to programming.. but thanks anyway..